# Simple Input function (using a comma)

Tags: python

I have a simple question: I want a comma to print after the user inserts their name - how can I do this without a space coming after the persons name?

```
name = input("Enter your name:")
print("Hi",name,"how are you?")
```

I can put a comma before how but then I have a space after the persons name. I want a comma straight after the name with no space.

For example:
Hi Bob, how are you?
NOT
Hi Bob ,how are you?

Thanks and sorry if this is trivial
Alvis

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: please give more info. What have you tried? what language are you trying to use? Are there any error?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it was Python

Comment: Don't mention it in a comment, use tags.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are using Python:

```
print("Hi %s, how are you?" % name)
```

Comment: Awesome! Works perfect! Thank Primoz

Comment: @AlvisPalmucci Great, you can accept the answer if it was helpful to you. :)